# How to create specific pattern overlay above an image?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

Basically a background image with pattern overlay that only covers half of the image. On the pattern have some text and may be a link.

[image: A background image with pattern overlay that only covers half of the image and have some text]

Below is what I've tried so far. I am able to achieve the look but not sure if its the right way to do things.

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <div class="my-custom-container">
    <div class="banner">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default mynavbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
              the_custom_logo();
            }?>
          </div>
          <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'top',
            'menu_class'     => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'   => 'myNavbar',
            'items_wrap'     => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">%3$s</ul>'
          ));?>
         </div>
       </nav>
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  section {
    background-color: #4E4F56;
  }
  .my-custom-container {
    width:1366px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .banner {
    background: url('img/homepage-bg-banner.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 777px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mynavbar {
    top: 55px;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .my-custom-container:before, .my-custom-container:after {
    background: url("img/pattern-iq4s-525.png") repeat-y;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to achive this exact pattern with CSS only? Or an image Overlay? We need more Info. And preferably a little bit of your code. I mean ... you HAVE tried anything before asking, have you?

Answer (score 3):

`SVG` is the best and recommended way to create such shapes.

We can use `SVG`'s `path` element to create this shape and fill it with some solid color, gradient or even pattern.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shape in `path` element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Below is the necessary code:

```
<path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#0085ca"
      d="M0,0 h458
         c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-9
         c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h16
         ....
         ....
         ....
         c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h11
         h-470 z
         M412,10 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-3 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
         M489,0 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-8 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
         ....
         ....
         M461,280 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
         ....
         ....
         M420,470 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-6 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z" />
```

Below is a brief description of the above code:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. Usually it appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `h` command is used to draw horizontal lines.
- `c` command is used to draw curves.
- `a` command is used to draw arcs.

Path commands comes in 2 variants. An *Uppercase* command specifies absolute coordinates while *Lowercase* specifies relative coordinates.

`fill-rule` attribute defines which point should be inside a `path`. It has 2 possible values i.e `nonzero` and `evenodd`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule) is a detailed description of this attribute.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

**Working Demo:**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.banner {
  background: #333 url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/hd-dark-wallpapers-4.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
.banner .shape {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 49%;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.caption {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.caption-holder {
  font-family: Airal, sans-serif;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
 <div class="caption">
   <div class="caption-holder">CAPTION GOES HERE...</div>
 </div>
 <svg width="505" height="475" viewBox="0 0 505 475" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="shape">
   <path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#0085ca"
       d="M0,0 h458 
          c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-9 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h16 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-22 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h8 
          c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-19 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h38 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-19 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h27
          c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-44 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h21 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-20 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h15
          c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-6 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h17 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-30 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h22 
                 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-15 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h28 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-13 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h29
                 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-50 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h22 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-4 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h15
              c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-26 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h3 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-16 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h17 
   c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-7 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h22 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-13 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h5
              c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-8 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h41 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-51 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h15
              c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-30 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h29 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-7 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h19
              c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-11 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h20 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-25 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h11
              c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-23 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h39 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-23 c-8,0 -8,10 0,10 h11
              h-470 z
          M412,10 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-3 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M489,0 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-8 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M420,30 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M490,20 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M480,40 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-6 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M420,70 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-3 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M495,80 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M485,100 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-9 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M407,110 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M477,140 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M485,160 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-9 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M415,170 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-3 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M492,180 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M430,190 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M481,220 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-3 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M425,230 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-3 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M479,260 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-18 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M495,260 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M408,270 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M461,280 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M419,290 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M483,300 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-3 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M479,320 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-11 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M425,330 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M477,360 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-7 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M497,360 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M470,380 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M490,400 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-8 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M412,410 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-4 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z M490,420 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10
       M420,430 a5 5 0 1 0 0 10 a5 5 0 1 0 0 -10 M480,440 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-6 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z
       M420,470 c8,0 8,10 0,10 h-6 c-8,0 -8,-10 0,-10 z" />
 </svg>
</div>
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for the instructions Mohammad. Very helpful

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, i would like to know how you managed to create the svg pattern? Have you used any tool?

Comment: @RDRAO No, I've not used any tool. Its all hand written. At first look it seems very lengthy code. However once the understanding of basic `c` and `q` commands are clear, its not very difficult. In this particular case I had to think about only a few entries. Others were just copy paste with a few minor changes.